# Online Pdf viewer with pinch zoom throws exception after close activity

Tags: android-studio, webview

I want to open a PDF file from server in web-view with zoom facilities.
I am using webView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true) but it throws an exception after close activity.

I am using below code:

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    webView.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
            });
            webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + data.getTypeUrl());
```

Exception is :

android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity has leaked window android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$Container that was originally added here

Comment: Post your exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 // make sure your pinch zoom is enabled
 webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

// don't show the zoom controls
 webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```